# Nvim external commands to write and delete files inside a function

Tags: external-command, functions

I use Neovim in a Linux (Arch Linux) environment. I have written a function to help me preview my markdown documents in PDF format without using a whole plugin. I've also added a simple command named "Prev" to call this function.

Here's the relevant part of my vimrc file :

```
function! s:pdf_preview()
    ! pandoc % -s -f markdown -t odt -o ~/.cache/%:t:r.odt > ~/.cache/%:t:r_Prev_log.txt 2>&1
    ! soffice --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir ~/.cache ~/.cache/%:t:r.odt >> ~/.cache/%:t:r_Prev_log.txt 2>&1
    ! zathura ~/.cache/%:t:r.pdf >> ~/.cache/%:t:r_Prev_log.txt 2>&1
endfunction
command Prev call s:pdf_preview()
```

Note : I'm using `soffice` to convert from odt to pdf to avoid installing a LaTeX processor (which I think would be required by pandoc for a direct conversion from markdown to pdf).

I'd like to improve this function in two ways :

1. save the current file in the .cache folder before the "! pandoc" command, so that I can use this temporary file for the preview instead of having to save my document each time ;
2. delete the temporary files (the odt and the pdf files) once the preview with zathura is closed.

Thanx for any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:write {filename}` to save your file in a different location without changing the active buffer.

Regarding your second question, you could look at `:help job-control` which describes how to start asynchronous process in Neovim. The `on_exit` callback may be what you need. For example the following snippet prints a message after then seconds

```
function! Echo(job_id, data, event)
    echo "CLOSED!"
endfunction

call jobstart (
    \ [
    \ 'bash',
    \ '-c',
    \ 'for i in {1..10}; do echo hello $i!; sleep 1; done'],
    \ {'on_exit': 'Echo'})
```

So, `jobstart` takes two arguments, the first is a list with the command to execute, and the second is a dictionary that maps events to functions. You only care about exiting Zathura, that's why the example only includes the `on_exit` event. You could try to write a function mapped to the `on_exit` event that deletes the file when called, and a script executed by `jobstart` that launches Zathura and returns the control to Neovim when it is closed

Comment: Unfortunately, adding `! write ~/.cache/%:t:r.md` before the `pandoc` function does nothing : the file is not saved, and the message `write : /home/me/file.md is not connected` is returned.

Comment: That's because `:write` is a Neovim command, not an external command, so you should not prepend it with `!`

Comment: OK, it works without `!` but asks for a confirmation to overwrite the file if it already exists. Is there a way to avoid this ? By the way, I've read the "Concepts" and "Usage" pages of `:h job-control`, but haven't understood theme well. An example is given, but I don't see how to apply it to my use case.

Comment: You can use `:write! <filename>` to overwrite it. (BTW, the `:` at the beginning is optional in script files.) I’ll update the answer with an example for job control

Comment: Thank you very much for the example. I've tried to adapt it, but the function mapped to `on_exit` is not executed, thus the files are not deleted : `function! Echo(job_id, data, event) ! rm ~/.cache/%:t:r.md endfunction call jobstart ( \ ['zathura ~/.cache/%:t:r.pdf'], \ {'on_exit': 'Echo'})` (the formatting is bad, there are several lines obviously)

Comment: You may need to wrap your call to Zathura in a shell script to ensure the `on_exit` is executed when it is closed and not before. I don’t use Zathura at all so I’m guessing it returns exit codes when closed

Comment: But if I use a shell script, I wouldn't need `jobstart` at all, right ? That would make no sense.

Comment: Commands by default execute synchronously on Vim and Neovim. If you don’t care about your script blocking Neovim then you don’t need to call `jobstart`

Comment: Indeed I don't ;) Thank you very much for all the detailed explanations.